# Sqlite INSERT INTO with a group_concat which contains a subselect

Tags: sqlite, group-concat

I need to take data and combine to insert into an table as a menu code. The menu code takes the form LNNLLLL (L = Letter and N=Number) and it is made up of MenU Cycle (hard-coded, one off project), Week Number (1-3), Day Number (1-7 - Monday=1), MealCode, Customer Type Code (3 Letters). The following SELECT query returns exactly what I want insert. The hardcoded date is a known date from which the week number and day number can be derived ie it is a Week 1 Monday.

```
SELECT  group_concat('C' || CASE 
        WHEN (CAST(julianday(mealdate) AS INT) - cast(julianday('2022-08-22') AS INT)) % 21 <= 6 THEN 1
        WHEN (CAST(julianday(mealdate) AS INT) - cast(julianday('2022-08-22') AS INT)) % 21 <= 13 THEN 2
        ELSE 3
    END ||
    CASE WHEN (CAST(julianday(mealdate) AS INT) - cast(julianday('2022-08-22') AS INT)) % 21 + 1 IN (1, 8, 15) THEN 1
         WHEN (CAST(julianday(mealdate) AS INT) - cast(julianday('2022-08-22') AS INT)) % 21 + 1 IN (2, 9, 16) THEN 2
         WHEN (CAST(julianday(mealdate) AS INT) - cast(julianday('2022-08-22') AS INT)) % 21 + 1 IN (3, 10, 17) THEN 3
         WHEN (CAST(julianday(mealdate) AS INT) - cast(julianday('2022-08-22') AS INT)) % 21 + 1 IN (4, 11, 18) THEN 4
         WHEN (CAST(julianday(mealdate) AS INT) - cast(julianday('2022-08-22') AS INT)) % 21 + 1 IN (5, 12, 19) THEN 5
         WHEN (CAST(julianday(mealdate) AS INT) - cast(julianday('2022-08-22') AS INT)) % 21 + 1 IN (6, 13, 20) THEN 6
         WHEN (CAST(julianday(mealdate) AS INT) - cast(julianday('2022-08-22') AS INT)) % 21 + 1 IN (7, 14, 21) THEN 7
    END ||
    MealCode ||
    (SELECT CustTypeCodeNew FROM CustomerNew WHERE CustCodeNew LIKE SalesOrderNew.CustomerCode)) AS MenuCode
FROM SalesOrderNew
GROUP BY SalesOrderID
```

Here is some output from that (I've added MealDate and MealCode to the select just to give better context to the resulting MenuCode column which is the one that needs inserted.

```
MealDate    MealCode    MenuCode
2022-08-23  K           C12KNRE
2022-08-23  K           C12KRES
2022-08-23  K           C12KSHO
2022-08-23  K           C12KRES
2022-08-25  T           C14TNRE
2022-08-25  T           C14TRES
2022-08-25  L           C14LNRE
2022-08-25  L           C14LNRE
2022-08-25  T           C14TNRE
```

The MenuCode column is currently filled with NULL values.

However if I put add a line above to `INSERT INTO SalesOrderNew (MenuCode)` I get this error `Result: NOT NULL constraint failed: SalesOrderNew.CustomerCode`. It does not seem to like the subselect that used within the group_contact. How do I go about resolving this?

Comment: I think you want to `UPDATE` rather than `INSERT`

Comment: Of course you are absolutely right. I clear the SalesOrderNew table and insert the data in fresh each time taking the latest data however I could not get the MenuCode inserted with the rest of the data so decided the easier option was just to add it afterwards so I was still in INSERT INTO mode when of course the rows already exist from the prior commit and it is an UPDATE. I should really have caught that on. Thanks for pointing out my error. Much appreciated.